# Hibernate statement hangs

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, freeze

From my junit test I'm calling a simple method to clear my table:

```
    @AfterClass  
public static void runAfterClass() {   
    //Clear db contents after tests         
    // NOTE this clears ALL data from the table
    try {
        System.out.println("deleting db contents");
        HibFunction.clearTable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Couldnt delete db contents"); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The clearTable looks like:

```
    public static void clearTable()
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try{
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.createQuery("delete from metadataPoC.hib.TestHib").executeUpdate();
    transaction.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }


}
```

All fairly simple stuff however my console output goes no further than:

```
deleting db contents
```

I am unsure why exactly a simple `delete from classname`

can cause such issues. The programme has just been hanging for 10mins with no failure or result from the junit test.

**Edit**

However I've isolated the problem to the clearTable() method moved it around in the code and as soon as it entered, hangs!
I'm not exactly sure why exactly, from the info I've found online my method seems correct from what I can see. But it has to be this method. I placed it in my `@BeforeClass` and the test just frozen when it got to it.

Bottom line there is a problem with the clearTable() method. Thou I've no idea what :(

EDIT 2

tracked down the problem to the executeupdate portion of the command for whatever reason it just stalls once it gets to the:

ParseUtil.encodePath(String, boolean) line: 100

Comment: Erm, what further output would you expect? I don't see any statements.

Comment: lol sorry, I forgot to mention my program does not complete. Nor does it remove the contents from the table in the database

Comment: How many rows are in the table when the clearTable() method is executed?

Comment: There is around 50-150ish nothing major. Althought the incremental id (PK) is around the 5700 mark from constantly trying this. I don't think this should have any real bearing thou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a deadlock between transaction of `clearTable()` method and transaction of the test method.

Make sure that you complete (commit or rollback) all transactions when leaving the test method.

Comment: I've got the transaction.commit(); at the end of each try block with the .rollback() contained within the catch. Finally block closing the session.
However I've isolated the problem to the clearTable() method moved it around in the code and as soon as it entered, hangs!